# SVG feColorMatrix filter looks different than CSS filter (sepia)

Tags: css, svg-filters

According to https://webplatform.github.io/docs/css/functions/sepia/ we should be able to use SVG filters - specifically a feColorMatrix - to mimic a sepia effect.

I was unable to reproduce the exact image effect and was wondering what I was doing wrong.
Here is my HTML:

```html
<svg width="640" height="550" viewBox="0 0 640 550">
    <defs>
        <filter id="matrix-sepia">
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
                           values="
            0.393 0.769 0.189 0 0
            0.349 0.686 0.168 0 0
            0.272 0.534 0.131 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image x="10" y="10" width="280" height="350" filter="sepia(1)" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Siberian-larch.jpg"/>
    <image x="310" y="10" width="280" height="350" filter="url(#matrix-sepia)" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Siberian-larch.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fLdu1rp8/8/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem.
The <filter> tag has a color-interpolation-filters attribute which defaults to linearRGB. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color-interpolation-filters)

When setting the value to sRGB, the resulting image looks the same as the CSS sepia filter one.

```html
<svg width="640" height="550" viewBox="0 0 640 550">
    <defs>
        <filter id="matrix-sepia"
                color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
                           values="
            0.393 0.769 0.189 0 0
            0.349 0.686 0.168 0 0
            0.272 0.534 0.131 0 0
            0 0 0 1 0"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image x="10" y="10" width="280" height="350" filter="sepia(1)" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Siberian-larch.jpg"/>
    <image x="310" y="10" width="280" height="350" filter="url(#matrix-sepia)" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/Siberian-larch.jpg"/>
</svg>
```